# How to auto-compress Images while uploading image in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

Here is my HTML form:

```html
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="">
    <input ng-model='file' type="file"/>
    <input type="submit" value='Submit'/>
</form>
```

I want to upload an image. Here if the file size is big(like 3 or 4 MB), I want to compress image automatically to 1MB or less than that. Any options are there to autocompress images in angularjs or javascript.

Comment: I don't think you are going to be able to do this in JavaScript.  There are many server side libraries to help, depending on which language you are using serverside.  Or companies like cloudinary.com can do it for you and host your images too.

Comment: check it out https://github.com/oukan/angular-image-compress

Comment: let me know if this is what you want so I could add an code example in answer

Comment: Yes This is what I want, can you add an code example @UsmanRana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/oukan/angular-image-compress) Angular directive compresses jpeg or png files using angularjs on client side. Read more about it [here](https://github.com/oukan/angular-image-compress)

This module depends on `angularjs`, so make sure you've added `angularjs` dependency and then `angular-image-compress.js`. Something like

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngImageCompress']);
```

This is how you can achieve what you want.

```
 <input id="inputImage" type="file" accept="image/*" image="image1" resize-max-height="800" resize-max-width="800" resize-quality="0.7" resize-type="image/jpg" ng-image-compress />
```

`Directives` used in above `input` tag are self explanatory

Comment: How can I create a customized Callback function using this?

My case will upload the compressed Images into the cloud once I selected the images in the FileUpload control, not when I click upload button or something.

I will not have a separate Upload action, instead I need to upload the Compressed image directly once the compression is applied.

How to achieve this in angularJS? Please assist to resolve my Issue.

Answer (score 2):

you can use image-compressor, where you can specify your desired height and width of your image.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-compressor